# continuously update the webpage without loading or clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was wondering if it was `.ready` that I would use if I wanted to continuously update a webpage.

So say if I had a page which counted the number of a particular tag and outputted that number onto a webpage. The number of tags can be changed using simple javascript.

On another page, I use a `$.get` to collect the information about the number of tags counted.
I want this to be updated automatically so when I change the number of tags on the page, the other page gets updated automatically. What I have done works so far, but I haven't done the crucial `$.get` part yet, which will make or break it.

So my question is: is it `$(document).ready(function(){})` I would use? If not is it possible and what function would I use?

Any suggestions ?

I have 2 webpages, one which just sets the number of tags and another which displays the number of tags. 
If I change the number of tags I want the display to automatically change with out having to manually reload the page

Comment: Is there any code to work with?

Comment: $(document).ready merly waits till the document is loaded before fireing the contained functions, so yes you will need to use $(document).ready, but you pobably will need to add some other functionality as well. Could you clarify your setup?

Comment: so how many pages are we talking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try setTimeout() function

```
var t = setTimeout(function (){
        window.location.reload();
    }, timeout); /*put a number of miliseconds*/
```

Comment: not the best solution, you can use ajax instead of window.location.reload() in order not to reload the whole page completely

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` to call the `$.get` function continuously.

You can try like this

```
// this will make sure the $.get function is called every second.
setInterval(function(){

            $.get({ ....
                     ...
                  });
          },1000);
```

Comment: Won't this be an overkill when the count of tag does not change frequently?